# Querying powerbi site using REST or JSON (from Linux)

Tags: sql, json, rest, powerbi, dax

I need to query a remote PowerBI server from non-MS system (Linux).

I found out that queries can be send via JSON but I struggle to understand the format. For example, how to retrieve the contents of all table columns given some WHERE and LIKE condition?

This is what I come up with (which does not work):

```
{
  "queries" : [
   {
     "ApplicationContext" : {
      "Sources" : [
        {
         "ReportId" : "ZZZ"
        }
      ],
      "DatasetId" : "YYY"
     },
     "Query" : {
      "Commands" : [
        {
         "SemanticQueryDataShapeCommand" : {
           "Query" : {
            "Where" : [
              {
               "Condition" : {
                 "In" : {
                  "Values" : [
                    [
                     {
                       "Like" : {
                        "Value" : "'%abc%'"
                       }
                     }
                    ],
                    null
                  ],
                  "Expressions" : [
                    {
                     "Column" : {
                       "Property" : "APROPERTY",
                       "Expression" : {
                        "SourceRef" : {
                          "Source" : "A"
                        }
                       }
                     }
                    }
                  ]
                 }
               }
              }
            ],
            "Select" : [
              {
               "Name" : "AVIEW.APROPERTY",
               "Column" : {
                 "Expression" : {
                  "SourceRef" : {
                    "Source" : "A"
                  }
                 },
                 "Property" : "APROPERTY"
               }
              }
            ],
            "Version" : "2",
            "From" : [
              {
               "Name" : "A",
               "Entity" : "AVIEW"
              }
            ]
           },
           "Binding" : {
            "Primary" : {
              "Groupings" : [
               {
                 "Projections" : [
                  "0",
                  "1"
                 ]
               }
              ]
            },
            "Version" : "1",
            "DataReduction" : {
              "DataVolume" : "3",
              "Primary" : {
               "Top" : {}
              }
            }
           }
         }
        }
      ]
     },
     "QueryId" : ""
   }
  ],
  "cancelQueries" : [],
  "modelId" : "XXX",
  "version" : "1.0.0"
}
```

This is the equivalent YAML perhaps it is more readable:

```
---
cancelQueries: []
modelId: XXX
queries:
  - ApplicationContext:
      DatasetId: YYY
      Sources:
        - ReportId: ZZZ
    Query:
      Commands:
        - SemanticQueryDataShapeCommand:
            Binding:
              DataReduction:
                DataVolume: 3
                Primary:
                  Top: {}
              Primary:
                Groupings:
                  - Projections:
                      - 0
                      - 1
              Version: 1
            Query:
              From:
                - Entity: AVIEW
                  Name: A
              Select:
                - Column:
                    Expression:
                      SourceRef:
                        Source: A
                    Property: APROPERTY
                  Name: AVIEW.APROPERTY
              Version: 2
              Where:
                - Condition:
                    In:
                      Expressions:
                        - Column:
                            Expression:
                              SourceRef:
                                Source: A
                            Property: APROPERTY
                      Values:
                        -
                          - Like:
                              Value: "'%abc%'"
                        -
    QueryId: ''
version: 1.0.0
```

Then I use `curl` to POST the above JSON data with appropriate headers to the public url (no credentials needed) which is something like `<URL>/public/reports/querydata`. This query method generally works and I succeeded with original query. But now I want to creating more complex queries and just hit this wall because most documentation does not talk about this kind of query language but it is either GUI-based or command-lets and DAX functions which require proprietary software installed.

What I need is some help with the above JSON and/or some pointers to documentation regarding the above query language, which I do not seem able to find, thanks.

Comment: what is the output of the above queries? or in other words, what type of information does it give you back (KPI values)?

Comment: First of all the result is JSON. Apart from metadata about col names, it contains an array with values, each representing a row of results. e.g. {"C":["A",1,2,3]} The big problem is when you get this: {"C":["A",1], "R":12} -I will leave it as a quiz as to what that means. Here is another one {"C":["A",3], "R":6}. What I haven't figure out yet is this {"C":["A",1], "R":12,"Ø":8} all [sic!]

Comment: Isn't it returning the dictionary where data is stored? Remember that PBI Engine when loads the data apply compressions. For all data type not Whole Number the compession is based on hash.

Answer (score 1):

I've been reverse engineering some PowerBI queries myself... don't have an exact answer for you on the query structure itself, but the "R" data in the results is a bit-field that is some sort of compression feature. It indicates which of the described fields are missing in the result "C" array.

My approach, which may or may not be correct, is to first insert empty array values in the corresponding places in the "C" array given the bit-field values, then you can sometimes fill in the "missing" fields using the same indexed field in the prior row's "C" array (usually when a missing string value would have been a duplicate of the prior row's), and leave missing numeric values null.